# How can we access members of the structure ,when our struct is an array?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct grades{
 char s1[DIM];
 char s2[DIM];
 int i;
 float f;

}grades;

void read(grades *s[]);
void write(grades *g[]);
int main() {
    grades v[5];
    read (&v);
    write(&v);
    return 0;
}



void read (grades *s[]){
    printf("enter the name of the student number and point");
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        scanf("%s %s %d %f",s[i]->s1,s[i]->s2,s[i]->i,s[i]->f );

    }

}

void write(grades *g[]){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%s %s %d %f\n",g[i]->s1,g[i]->s2,(g[i]->i)+5,(g[i]->f)+5 );

    }
```

in this short program, I want to define a struct to get students name, surname, number and then grade.
then add 5 grades to their grade and print it.
when we use array of structs, should we refer to the array, when we use it with pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared an array of structures

```
grades v[5];
```

So in this call

```
write(&v);
```

the expression `&v` has the type `grades ( * )[5]`. This pointer type is not compatible with the functions' parameter type that is implicitly adjusted to `grades **g`.

You need to declare the functions like

```
void read(grades *s, size_t n);
void write( const grades *g, size_t n);
```

and to call the functions like

```
read( v, 5 );
write( v, 5 );
```

This call of scanf

```
scanf("%s %s %d %f",s[i]->s1,s[i]->s2, s[i]->i, s[i]->f );
```

shall be rewritten at least like

```
scanf("%s %s %d %f",s[i].s1,s[i].s2, &s[i].i, &s[i].f );
```

Comment: Or of course it is acceptable to define the functions using the form `void read(grades s[], size_t n);`.  That is semantically identical to the recommendation in this answer, but for me, it reinforces the expectation that caller will usually pass an array as the first argument.

Comment: Thank you! What is siza_t here? is it same as  void *malloc (size_t size) we use in memory allocation?(unsigned integer)?

Comment: @sajjadeshghi size_t is the type of the value returned by the operator sizeof. The number of elements in an integer array can be calculated for example the following way sizeof( array ) / sizeof( int )  and teh type of the expression is size_t.

Comment: Thank you again, another question,here, why you dedicated "const" "void write( const grades *g, size_t n)"?

Comment: @sajjadeshghi It is because the array is not being changed within the function. It is a contract with the user of the function.

Comment: @sajjadeshghi If the answer was useful you can close the question select  the best answer. It will increase your reputation.:)